# How to load a fragment view in a tab

Tags: android-fragments, android-tabhost

I am trying to create tabs inside a fragment. I manage to create tab inside the fragment, but now I want to load different fragment for each tab (*fragment1.class and fragment2.class*).

Can anybody please suggest how can i load each fragment to their respective tabs?

Below is my main fragment that is holding the tabs.

Thanks a lot!

```
public class BusFragment extends Fragment {

    private TabHost mTabHost;
    View rootView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bus, container, false);
            mTabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
            mTabHost.setup();

            TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag");
            spec.setIndicator("Fragment1");
            spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));

                }
            });
            mTabHost.addTab(spec);

            spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
            spec.setIndicator("Fragment2");
            spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));
                }
            });
            mTabHost.addTab(spec);

            spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
            spec.setIndicator("Fragment3");
            spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return (new AnalogClock(getActivity()));
                }
            });
            mTabHost.addTab(spec);

            return rootView;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello If you want to load the fragment inside the fragment android provide the Child Fragment Manager instead of ordinary fragment manager. I had the same issue I had the fragment inside that tab when click on tab want to load the different fragments. see the below steps hope will help you.

Step 1. See I have StatisticsFragment with it layout fragment_statistics.

```
public class StatisticsFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_statistics,container, false);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),R.id.tabFrameLayout);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("WEEK").setIndicator(buildTabLayout(EnumStatistics.WEEKLY)),WeekFragment_.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("ALL").setIndicator(buildTabLayout(EnumStatistics.ALL)),DetailedFragment_.class, null);

        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnClickListener(new WeekTabClick());

        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new AllTabClick());

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private View buildTabLayout(EnumStatistics enumStatistics) {
        View tab;
        if (enumStatistics == EnumStatistics.WEEKLY) {
            tab = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_week_layout, null);
        } else if (enumStatistics == EnumStatistics.MONTHLY) {
            tab = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_month_layout, null);
        } else if (enumStatistics == EnumStatistics.YEAR) {
            tab = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_year_layout, null);
        } else {
            tab = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_detailed_layout, null);
        }
        return tab;
    }



    public class WeekTabClick implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mTabHost.getTabWidget().focusCurrentTab(0);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.tabFrameLayout, WeekFragment_.instantiate(getActivity(), WeekFragment_.class.getName()));
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

        }
    }

    public class AllTabClick implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mTabHost.getTabWidget().focusCurrentTab(1);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.tabFrameLayout, DetailedFragment_.instantiate(
                    getActivity(), DetailedFragment_.class.getName()));
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

In above `buildTabLayout` function intent to build the custom layout of tab widget you can put simple text or image that you want to show inside the tab widget.

Steps 2. fragment_statistics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:relaxis="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/croutonview"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you see in the above inside the layout tabFrameLayout we load the all child fragment Programmaticly.

Let me know if you have any question and doubt. thank you